# Get the system to turn on using a voltage source

Tags: transistors, latching

I am working on a project where i have a momentary push button and i am using this latching circuit to toggle between the two stats, the circuit is working fine.
I need to add a circuit to this one in order to turn when a voltage is detected in one of the phases of a bldc.
So basically, the system can be turned on/off with the button or turned on (only) when voltage is detected on one phase of the bldc.
I don't want to add any microcontroller to my circuit.

I've been working and used many different ways but none of them worked.
[image]

Comment: where would that motor be attached? also, why no microcontroller? this literally sounds like *the* classical reason microcontrollers were invented: discrete-state control using as little complexity as possible.

Comment: Thanks @MarcusMüller for the reply. I really do not know where the phase of the motor must be connected neither how. I am avoiding microcontrollers cause i am already using one which is on the load (Simulated with a led in the circuit). In my theory, that microcontroller won't get power unless the button is pushed so i can not use it (i believe) and i am not really willing to add another one to the circuit unless there is no choice.

Comment: Define all inputs and outputs with tolerances and actions required

Comment: your U1 gets power all the time. Why would the microcontroller not have that privilege? it would be sleeping all the time, and be using practically no current, anyway.

Comment: I guess i will go for a microcontroller then, i guess i ll be using an ATtiny85. Do you think it  is a good choice ?

Comment: _"I really do not know where the phase of the motor must be connected neither how."_ - can you tell us anything about it, eg. power source, what the motor is used for?  Why do you want to detect 'when a voltage is detected' in one of the phases of the motor?

Comment: Hey @BruceAbbott, thanks for the reply. The motor is controlled by an esc, it's power source is a battery of 24v - 10000 mAh. It is used on a skateboard. basically i want to turn on the system using a kick (whithout using accelerometers).

Comment: So the system can be turned on in two ways : 1 - with the button. 2 - with the kick. But only turned off using the button.